# How to click on a button and toast appear

Tags: android, flash, button, toast

```
hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
                .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);  



Switch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Switch_off);    

Switch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick( View vw) {
        if (vw.getId() == R.id.Switch_off && !hasFlash) {
            Log.d("tagname","string you want to execute");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Sorry,your device doesn't support flashlight",
                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

I am seeking into pressing switch and if I don't have flash, my toast to appear.
Although right now when I run this code, and I press the button even though I don't have flash, it switches normally without off course any flash to open. 
Some devices, might not have flash that's why I want, when they press button to leave them a message with toast

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: can you explain the problem here?

Comment: Include the code that determines the value of `hasFlash`

Comment: what's problem you are facing here?

Comment: i want devices without flash to show the message

Answer (score 0):

Try this modified code, now your button will be disabled when device has no flash.

```
hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
                .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);  



Switch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Switch_off);    

if (!hasFlash) {
            Log.d("tagname","string you want to execute");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Sorry,your device doesn't support flashlight",
                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        switch.setEnabled(false);
        }

Switch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick( View vw) {
        //Do your work here
    }
});
```